# IBM DB2 v10.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 Can not locate C header files

Tags: c, stored-procedures, db2

I am working on an Ubuntu v12.04 machine with IBM DB2 v10.1 Enterprise edition on it. The DB2 installation directory is located at:

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/
```

But under the include/ directory there is only the following file:

```
ls /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/include/
asn.h
```

Where are the rest of the C headers located? Do I need to install some additional package? I have already installed the Client Package provided with the IBM DB2 installer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have selected the Application Development Tools package during the server installation -- they are not installed by default. You can rerun the server installation or install the IBM Data Server Client (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have actually figured it out by myself and I am currently doing that. However, thank you for answering. :-)